# Why do "X associate" and "associate X" have such different meanings?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

[This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/206784/37813) describes the American English term "stock associate", as meaning a relatively low paid store worker who fills shelves.

By contrast, high status work seems to have the job descriptor after the word "associate" ("associate director", "associate justice", "associate" member of some professional body).

Is it always/usually the case, that "associate" after the rest of the job title would have a different significance to "associate" before the rest of the job title? If so, why?

Comment: They're arbitrary, ideosyncratic job titles. There isn't really any logic to it.

Comment: Note that in your second set of examples, "associate" means they have *less* power. An associate justice is a lower job than the chief justic. An associate producer is lower than an executive producer.

Comment: The first kind are euphemisms. They used to call stock associates "stock boys", which was demeaning (not to mention sexist). Changing to "associate" makes it sound *more* important.

Comment: Even arbitrary terms and societally functional (non-swear) euphemisms get chosen and used because they _feel_ like they fit, or _feel_ like they are appropriate. When scrutinised they are often revealing and not arbitrary at all. Why was the widely adopted term not "associate stocker" or "associate stock manager" or something fitting with existing usage, if that was the case, for example? Why the different word order vs. the "status" usage? Not sure that "because it is", really reveals the factors behind the order difference when the use of "X associate" gained traction for lower paid work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order "associate X" uses "associate" as an adjective. This form is used when the job is a variation of X. For instance, associate justice and chief justice are types of justices, and associate producer is a lower-ranked producer. The relevant definitions from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/associate) are

> 1. closely connected (as in function or office) with another : sharing in responsibility or authority
> 2. having secondary or subordinate status

The order "X associate" uses "associate" as a noun, and X modifies it. This is used when the job relates to X. A stock associate works with stock, a sales associate makes sales. The relevant definitions are:

> 1. a. PARTNER, COLLEAGUE
> 2. a. an entry-level member (as of a learned society, professional organization, or profession)

In many cases, the "X associate" terms have arisen as euphemisms that make these jobs sound more important. Stock associates used to be called stock boys, sales associates were sales clerks or salesmen/saleswomen.

Comment: Interesting and plausible. Any references for it? That would also imply that in "Associate X", X is a _job role_, while in "X associate", X is an _object or entity_ which might be central to the role but isn't a role itself? But if so, why is "stock" different from "justice"? Or is the latter being used in the sense of "justice=person working in law" rather than "justice=that which is the central focus of such a person"? Can you elaborate the answer a bit? Thanks.

Comment: justice is a synonym for judge.

Comment: I've added some dictionary definitions that help.

Comment: @Stilez I am now imagining a police officer getting their position retitled to "justice associate".

Comment: @nick012000 "law enforcement associate" is not unlikely ("legal associate" sounds like an assistant to a lawyer). Note that "police officer" is already an evolution from "policeman" or simply "cop".